# How to Align A Table in Java

Tags: java, arrays, alignment

How to align my Array so it does not look that awful?

In other words, how do I format a table that is readable?

The `System.out.print(" ");` is a pretty inefficient manner for spacing for a table...

```
public class TaylorSin {
   public static void main(String[] args ) {
   double[][] ArrayX = new double[201][4];
   for (int i = 0; i < ArrayX.length; i++) { 
      System.out.print(ArrayX[i][0] = - 1 + (i * 0.01));
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(ArrayX[i][1] = Math.sin(- 1 + (i * 0.01)));
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(ArrayX[i][2] = taylorSin(- 1 + (i * 0.01)));
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(ArrayX[i][3] = Math.abs(Math.sin(- 1 + (i * 0.01)) - taylorSin(- 1 + (i * 0.01))));

            System.out.println();
        }       
    }

        public static int calculateFactorial(int n)             
        {       
            int facto = 1;      
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)        
            {facto = facto * i;}        
            return facto;           
        }

        public static double calculateExponent(double base, int exponent)           
        {   
            if(exponent == 0){return 1;}   
            else {return base * calculateExponent(base, exponent - 1);}                     
        }       

        public static double calculateTerm(double base, int exponent, int n)            
        {           
            double term = 0.0;          
            term = (calculateExponent(base, exponent)/calculateFactorial(n));               
            return term;            
        }

        public static double sumOfTerms(double base, int exponent, int n)           
        {               
            double summation = 0;               
            for (int i = 1; i <= 21; i = i +2)          
            {               
                if (i == 3 || i == 7 || i == 11 || i == 15 || i == 19)              
                {                   
                summation = summation - calculateTerm(base, i, i);                                      
                }                   
                else                    
                {                   
                summation = summation + calculateTerm(base, i, i);                  
                }               
            }           
        return summation;           
        }

        public static double taylorSin(double base)         
        {           
        double result = 0;          
        int exponent = 1;
        int n = 1;          
        result = sumOfTerms(base, exponent, n);                     
        return result;          
        }           
}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.printf` or `System.out.format`, it's similar (but not equal) to C `printf` function.

Comment: how do you get the output. Try to use `\t`

Comment: @asifsid88 if you want to make it work like a table, you don't use `\t` instead you set a specific size for each column like `%20d` or `%15s`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks :) That added to my knowledge!! Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System.out.printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to format your output like this:

```
public class TaylorSin {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // How to align my Array so it does not look that awful?
        // In other words, How do I format a table that is readable?
        // The System.out.print(" "); is a pretty inefficient manner for spacing
        // for a table...
        double[][] ArrayX = new double[201][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayX.length; i++)

        {
            System.out.printf("%-15f", ArrayX[i][0] = -1 + (i * 0.01));
            System.out.print(" ");

            System.out
                    .printf("%-15f", ArrayX[i][1] = Math.sin(-1 + (i * 0.01)));
            System.out.print(" ");

            System.out.printf("%-15f",
                    ArrayX[i][2] = taylorSin(-1 + (i * 0.01)));
            System.out.print(" ");

            System.out.printf(
                    "%-15f",
                    ArrayX[i][3] = Math.abs(Math.sin(-1 + (i * 0.01))
                            - taylorSin(-1 + (i * 0.01))));

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static int calculateFactorial(int n)

    {

        int facto = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)

        {
            facto = facto * i;
        }

        return facto;

    }

    public static double calculateExponent(double base, int exponent)

    {

        if (exponent == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        else {
            return base * calculateExponent(base, exponent - 1);
        }

    }

    public static double calculateTerm(double base, int exponent, int n)

    {

        double term = 0.0;

        term = (calculateExponent(base, exponent) / calculateFactorial(n));

        return term;

    }

    public static double sumOfTerms(double base, int exponent, int n)

    {

        double summation = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 21; i = i + 2)

        {

            if (i == 3 || i == 7 || i == 11 || i == 15 || i == 19)

            {

                summation = summation - calculateTerm(base, i, i);

            }

            else

            {

                summation = summation + calculateTerm(base, i, i);

            }

        }

        return summation;

    }

    public static double taylorSin(double base)

    {

        double result = 0;

        int exponent = 1;
        int n = 1;

        result = sumOfTerms(base, exponent, n);

        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [java.io.PrintStream.printf( format , data... )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to formatted print

Format string is described in [Format string syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

The flag format you may use is `width`: `%-20s` or `%12.4f`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Moreover, you may want to format the numbers if that's ok to do so.

```
    { 
        System.out.print(ArrayX[i][0] = - 1 + (i * 0.01));
        System.out.print("\t");

        System.out.print(ArrayX[i][1] = Math.sin(- 1 + (i * 0.01)));
        System.out.print("\t");

        System.out.print(ArrayX[i][2] = taylorSin(- 1 + (i * 0.01)));
        System.out.print("\t");

        System.out.print(ArrayX[i][3] = Math.abs(Math.sin(- 1 + (i * 0.01)) -   taylorSin(- 1 + (i * 0.01))));
        System.out.print("\t");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Comment: see @LuiggiMendoza comment in the question

Comment: @Iswanto San agreed. It happened in a matter of minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's buit-in System.out.printf() and take a look at the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) class. You can do something like this.

```
System.out.printf("%f %f %f %f\n", ArrayX[i][0], ArrayX[i][1], ArrayX[i][1], ArrayX[i][2], ArrayX[i][3]);
```